# Better way to do announcements?

Tags: 2013, announcements

Just looking for a better announcements solution. I've tried popups, banners, and other solutions, but they aren't working for my users.
I would like something like this: https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/88/entryid/653/how-you-make-sharepoint-announcements-grab-attention-easily-using-csr.aspx and have tried implementing it but it will not work.
Any ideas/Tools/better solutions?

Comment: As the URL suggested and I also believe CSR is a good way to customize the way you want data to be represented. Did you tried CSR? If so what problem you faced?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a sharepoint modal on page load? If the user clicks "OK", you could write a cookie for them that tells the page not to load the announcement anymore, or you can continue to popup for every page load.